# Sort model based on defined order

Tags: ember.js

So what I'm setting out to do is generally gross and horrible, but I have to work with the data I'm given.

I have a questionnaire that is the same for all users. It has the following attributes: id, name, required. In the database, the name fields appear in this order:

```
cell_phone
city
date_of_birth
email
first_name
graduation_year
last_name
phone
state
coach
name
```

This order is based on their ids. I need them to appear on the page grouped in a way that is more intuitive, i.e.:

```
first_name
last_name
email
phone
city
state
zip
...
```

In my route, I simply set the model:

```
userId = App.Session.get("userId")
@store.find("questionnaire", userId: userId)
```

Is there a way to either map over the array that comes back from the model and basically hard code this order or sort the model in the controller to match a given order based on name or index?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array with the order you want, then sort by the item's index:

```
var order = [
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'email',
    'phone',
    'city',
    'state',
    'zip'
];

questions.sort(function(a, b) {
    return order.indexOf(a.name) - order.indexOf(b.name);
});
```

You could put that logic into a computed property or map the data when `find` completes

Comment: Great! Does this belong in the controller?

Comment: Yes. Create a computed property in the controller which depends on `model`